# How to evaluate $I=\iiint dr_{12}dr_{13}dr_{14}$ analytically/numerically?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, definite-integrals

How to evaluate this integral analytically or numerically:

$$
I=\iiint dr_{12}dr_{13}dr_{14}
$$

constrained by

$$
r_{12}<r_0,\\r_{23}<r_0,\\r_{34}<r_0,
$$

where $r_0$ is a given real number and
$$r_{ij}=\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2+(z_i-z_j)^2}$$

I have been that this integral cannot be calculated analytically and one way for the numerical calculation is to use [Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) methods, but I don't know how to implement this in MATLAB.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: Thanks. How should I give the constraints to this function? Note that the differentials are $dr_{12}$, $dr_{13}$, and $dr_{14}$, while the constraints are imposed on $r_{12}$, $r_{23}$, and $r_{34}$.